# clSetKernelArg arg_value other than memory object

Tags: opencl

In OpenCL, can I set kernel argument as following?

```
cl_uint a = 0;
kernel.setArg(0, sizeof(a), &a);
```

I want to **read&write** one value from/to a kernel function, not only write to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a kernel argument in this manner can only be used for *inputs* to the kernel. Any output you want to read (either in a subsequent kernel or from the host program) must be written to a buffer or an image. In your case, that means you need to create a single-element buffer and pass the buffer to the kernel.

One way to think about this is that when you call setArg with the parameter &a, the OpenCL kernel is using the *value* of a, not the *location* of a. If the kernel were to write to kernel argument zero, your host program would have no way of recovering the value that was written.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will use cl::Buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code creates an argument of type `unsigned int`, not pointer to `unsigned int`.
`clSetKernelArg` takes a **pointer to the argument value**, not the value itself.
If you want to pass a pointer argument, you will have to create a buffer with `clCreateBuffer` (even if it's just one value in there) and call `clSetKernelArg` with the resulting `cl_mem`.

The following code creates a buffer for 1 `cl_uint` in **__global** memory, and copies the value of `my_value` to it. After running the kernel, it copies the (possibly modified) value back to `my_value`.

```
cl_uint my_value = 0;
const unsigned int count = 1;
// Allocate buffer
cl_mem hDeviceMem = clCreateBuffer(hContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, count * sizeof(cl_uint), &my_value, &nError);
// Set pointer to buffer as argument
clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &hDeviceMem);
// Run kernel
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(...);
// Copy values back
clEnqueueReadBuffer(hCmdQueue, hDeviceMem, CL_TRUE, 0, count * sizeof(cl_uint), &my_value, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Your kernel should then look like this:

```
__kernel void myKernel(__global unsigned int* value)
{
    // read/write to *value here
}
```

Comment: instead of clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &hDeviceMem);It should be clSetKernelArg(hKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&hDeviceMem)

Comment: Conversion from any pointer to a void pointer is implicit in both C and C++

Answer (score 0):

This should work the same as sending a 1-length vector as a param. You might have to use __global uint aParam in your kernel definition.